# Creating Requirement based Test Suite fails through TFS API but works through Web Portal

Tags: tfs

Unable to create a Requirements based Test Suite using TFS .NET API nor the REST API in TFS 2015.  Using the TFS web portal this is possible.

I understand the reason why the API's fail, which is that the EPIC work items I'm using are not in the "Requirement Category." However, the TFS web portal lets me use these same EPIC work item as the requirement for a requirements based test suite.  Go figure?

Since the project I'm working on involves a Fortune 500 company it is no simple feat to add EPICs to the "Requirement Category."  Since the TFS web portal uses some kind of work-around I'm wondering if someone can clue me in as to how it's being done, and if I can take advantage of it using the .NET or REST APIs.

Thanks

Comment: TFS .NET API gives this error message: The following work item type is not valid: Epic. You must specify a valid work item type that belongs to the category with reference name Microsoft.RequirementCategory

Comment: TFS REST API gives this error message: InvalidPropertyException: The workitem with id 11279 is not of type requirement category

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce your issue on my side. According to the REST api of [Create a test suite](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/test/suites#create-a-test-suite), parameter requirementIds supports categories of requirement type are: Epic, Feature, Requirement, and Bug. But REST api can not support Epic work items actually:

[image]

I have report a feedback at website below, we will get response soon:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/231035/creating-requirement-based-test-suite-fails-throug.html

Comment: Thanks Cece, looking forward to the response